# Django redirect with message after XMLHttpRequest

Tags: django, post, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I have a template that send a JSON to my backend with a POST XMLHttpRequest with

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
    var theUrl = "newSeq";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(my_json));
```

The Django backend manage the request with

```
def newSeq(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.body)
        messages.success(request, "Ricevuto")
        return redirect("newSeq")
    
    return render(
        request,
        'dashboard/newSeq.html',
        {

        }
    )
```

My issue is that the redirect doesn't work and on the frontend I have the error `the cookies "messages" has been rejected because it is already expired`

Is there a way to delete the specific cookies and make the page redirect with the correct message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend that you replace [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) for the [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Also, you do not need to mess with `Cookies` yourself, let the framework take care of it for you with its [`middlewares`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/messages/#module-django.contrib.messages).

The main problem is that you are returning a full HTML page (upon telling the Framework to `render` `dashboard/newSeq.html`). In reality you only need to `redirect` to another view and we can also do that with JavaScript. Here is a simple example:

views.py

```
def fetch_new_seq(request):
    """Attach message and reverse resolve redirection URL"""
    messages.success(request, "Ricevuto")
    redirect_url = reverse('new-seq')
    return JsonResponse({'url': redirect_url})
```

template.html

```
...
<script>
    function getCookie(name) {
        ...
    }

    async function postData() {
        const url = "http://localhost:8000/fetch/new/seq/"
        const data = {some: "data"}
        const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        return await response.json()
    }
    
    postData().then((data) => { 
        window.location.replace(data.url); 
    });
</script>
...
```

Comment: I found out that I can basically do the same with just `document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = xmlhttp.response;` when `onreadystatechange`. Is it correct (it works tho)

Comment: What you are doing is replace the whole `HTML` tag content. And, for this `specific` case I would say that is okay, since you are going to redirect and render a new page anyway. But, keep in mind that these types of requests are mostly used to partially update your pages (without reloading it entirely) and typically you want to return data and then manipulate the `DOM` using `JavaScript` to display such.